# Lemma 8.2.2 from Terence Tao Vol1

Tags: real-analysis

Let X be a set, and let $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that the series $\Sigma_{x \in X} f(x)$ is absolutely convergent. Then the set $\{x \in X : f(x) \neq 0\}$ is at most countable.

Book's hint:

The sets $\{x \in X : f(x) > \frac{1}{n} \}$ with cardinality at most Mn, where $$M := sup \{ \Sigma_{x \in A} |f(x)| : A \subset X, A\ is \ finite\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n$, the set $F_n:=\{x:|f(x)|>\frac1n\}$ is finite otherwise, one can subtract a sequence $\{x_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of different elements in $F_n$. But then $\sum_{x\in X}|f(x)|\geq \sum_k|f(x_k)|\geq\sum_k\frac{1}{n}=\infty$ contradicting the  convergence of $\sum_x|f(x)|$.

Since $F=\{x:f(x)\neq0\}=\bigcup_nF_n$, one concludes that $F$ is at most countable.

Comment: Please see my answer as well and my other question.

Comment: Sure, I understand what you mean with different elements. I like your answer. I will accept it soon.

Comment: I asked another question about the cardinality. I don't know where it enters in the equation ?

Comment: The countable union  of countable sets is countable. $F$ is the countable union o f countable (in fact finite) sets. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: It is still not clear. Specially the assertion in the last sum.

Comment: Oliver Diaz I posted an answer can you check it please?

Answer (score 3):

You’ve given no justification for your assertion that

$$\sum_{x\in A}|f(x)|=\sum_{k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}}\left|f\big(g(k)\big)\right|\ge\frac1n\cdot n=1\,,$$

which in any case doesn’t make sense. In order for $f(x)$ to make sense, $x$ must be an element of $X$, so $A$ must be a subset of $X$. You’ve not told us what $A$ is, but it seems likely that you intended it to be the $A_n$ that you defined in the previous sentence, in which case there’s no reason to think that it’s a subset of $X$: we have no reason to believe that $X$ contains any integers at all.

$\sum_{k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}}\left|f\big(g(k)\big)\right|$ makes sense for any $g:\Bbb N\to X$, but since you’ve not specified what function $g$ is, we have no reason to think that each $\left|f\big(g(k)\big)\right|\ge\frac1n$.

The point of the hint is that if there were more than $Mn$ elements $x\in X$ such that $|f(x)|\ge\frac1n$, we could take a set $A$ of more than $Mn$ of these elements and have

$$\sum_{x\in A}|f(x)|>Mn\cdot\frac1n=M\,,$$

contradicting the definition of $M$. Thus, for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ the set

$$S_n=\left\{x\in X:|f(x)|\ge\frac1n\right\}$$

is finite. Let $S=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}S_n$; this is the union of countably many countable (in fact finite) sets, so it is countable.

Now suppose that $x\in X$, and $f(x)\ne 0$; then there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $|f(x)|\ge\frac1n$, i.e., such that $x\in S_n\subseteq S$. Thus, there are at most countably many $x\in X$ such that $|f(x)|\ne 0$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention $g : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$, that is how we construct the addition on countable sets that isn't just $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: I have adjusted my answer based on the answers here. I will accept the answer soon.

Comment: You *mentioned* it, but you failed to *define* it, so your expression $\sum_{k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}}f\big(g(k)\big)$ cannot be evaluated.

Comment: Brian M. Scott I edited my answer. Can you check it ?

Comment: @IWantToLearn: I’m sorry, but the new displayed line makes no more sense than the original one, though the errors are different ones, and does not justify the conclusion that $\sum_{x\in X}|f(x)|$ is infinite.

Comment: @egreg: You’re right, of course; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To prove finite part and the restriction on the card this is my argument. Can you check it?

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $S := \{x \in X : |f(x)| > \frac{1}{n}\}$. Assume S is infinite, then set $S = \{ \Sigma_{x \in A} |f(x)| : A \subset S, A$ finite $\}$ <  $M = sup \{ \Sigma_{x \in A} |f(x)| : A \subset X, A$ finite $\} < \infty$

I used the fact that convergence happens iff we have the condition $M < \infty$.

By similar argument to above the card(S) < Mn.

Comment: Oliver Diaz that would be amazing. I want to understand that how it works.

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe it is clear now how it works!